# Draw a CCNode with Box2D body in cocos2d version 3

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

i have a question about drawing a CCNode which has a box2D body. In a ealier version of cocos2d there is this class `CCPhysicSprite`, which override the important methods of `CCNode` to make it possible to call some properties like position, nodeToParentTransform etc..

I have implemented these methods in class which inherit from `CCNode`.

So actually i would like to know how can i draw the box2D body in my draw method. I mean draw a circle for example at exactly the right position as my body has.

When i call the draw method manual from parentnode (the ccnodes with box2D body are not added), all positions are right.

Like this here:

```
-(void)draw{

    for (MyPhysicNode * node in _physicsNodeToDraw){

    [node draw]

    }

 }
```

But when i add the nodes to the parent and don't call the draw method manual the position are completely wrong.

[Here](https://github.com/Birkemose/cocos2d-v3/blob/master/Cocos2D-reference/libs/cocos2d/CCPhysicsSprite.mm) is the link to the ccphysicssprite

I think the problem is the `CCNode` to parent transform, but i don't know how can i implement this.

One second question in aspect to the above problem: Is it recommend to use the default draw method. I mean to add CCNode to a parent node and the parent call the draw and update method automatically. Or make this no different to call the update and draw methods manually. The thing with  relative position make no different for me.

Thank you in advance. I hope anyone can understand me

Greetings Alex